# preg_match crush apache

Tags: regex, apache, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a template engine. Parsing tpl files. But when tpl files have a lot of {if},{foreach} or {language} blocks preg_match crush apache.

This my preg_match function;

```
preg_match_all('$\{(if|foreach)[\s]*(.*?)[\s]*\}((?:[^{]*(?:\{(?!\/?(if|foreach)[^}]*\})[^{]*)*|(?R))*)\{\/\1\}$iu',$content,$output);
```

And this is apache logs

```
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:41.135620 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00428: Parent: child process 7620 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:41.235425 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:41.236426 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:41.236426 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:41.284459 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9668
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:41.642877 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9668:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:42.047450 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00428: Parent: child process 9668 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:42.147702 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:42.147702 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:42.147702 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:42.194580 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1888:tid 552] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10824
[Sun Jun 12 21:04:42.487866 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10824:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

But when i try regex101.com, its succesfuly matching without any errors. https://regex101.com/r/uW8rZ8/3

Comment: I think this part [`\{(if|foreach)[\s]*(.*?)[\s]*\}`](https://regex101.com/r/rN1kM8/1) is causing a lot of backtracking. Alternative: [`{(if|foreach)\s*([^}]*[^}\s])\s*}`](https://regex101.com/r/rN1kM8/2) but there are great answers already (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your pattern works with regex101, you are near the catastrophic bactracking. The reason why you pattern works with regex101 and not with your server is simple: configurations are not the same.

Two things are missing in your pattern:

- the use of possessive quantifiers (or atomic groups) to forbid backtracking where it isn't useful.
- unrolling things like `(?:A|B)*` to `A*+(?:BA*)*+` to avoid the alternation and to reduce the number of steps.

Following these advices will make your pattern about 3x more efficient:

```
~
{ (if\b|foreach\b) \s*+
( [^\s}]*+ (?:\s+[^\s}]+)*+ ) \s* }
(
    [^{]*+
    (?:  { (?!/?if\b|/?foreach\b) [^{]*
      |  (?R)                     [^{]* )*+

)
{/\1}
~ixu
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vR3uB4/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex101 may be working without any errors, but it's not working well. If you take a look, it says: `2 matches - 10792 steps`, which means your regex is probably catastrophically backtracking. If it's not, then you're probably not using the right tool... Have you considered using an *actual* parser? One that was designed to handle recursive matching?

If you still feel that this *needs* to be done with regexes, you need to fix some flaws.

I'm not familiar with the setup you have to directly help you with the errors you are getting (are they even errors?), but I think that you need to solve some more pressing issues before you can tackle the other issues. It's possible that this process may solve the issue you are having, since it's very possibly related.

The biggest thing for me right now is your regex **lacks readability**. I have no clue what your regex does. And I'm not your average programmer... I LOVE regexes, and I'm usually able to read them easily. But not this one. (Part of the problem may also be the fact that it's not really clear *why* you're using this regex.)

My first suggestion would be to use the `x` modifier, which allows you to use spacing, like you would in a normal program. I have modified your original regex to use spacing, and I also have removed excessive backslashes:

```
{(if|foreach)
[\s]*
(.*?)
[\s]*}
((?:
  [^{]*
  (?:{
    (?!/?
      (if|foreach)[^}]*}
    )
    [^{]*
  )*|(?R))*
)
{/\1}
```

---

I have written a similar recursive parser with regexes in the past, so I have some experience with this type of thing. From what I remember, my parser was faster, and it was far more readable (given it flows similar to a BNF-style parser). I think I now how something that is faster, based off my parser:

```
$re = "`
{(if)     ((?&exp))}(*PRUNE)\s*((?&line)*)\s*(*PRUNE){/if}|
{(foreach)((?&exp))*}(*PRUNE)\s*((?&line)*)\s*(*PRUNE){/foreach}
|(?&other)+

|(*F)(?:
   (?'line'  (?&if)|(?&for)|(?&other)+)
   (?'if'    {if     (?&exp)}(*PRUNE)\s*(?&line)*\s*(*PRUNE){/if})
   (?'for'   {foreach(?&exp)}(*PRUNE)\s*(?&line)*\s*(*PRUNE){/foreach})
   (?'other' ([^{]+|{)(?! (/?if|/?foreach)))
   (?'exp'   [^}]*)
)`xis";
```